# PHP PDO SELECT SQL involving VARCHAR does not work when WHERE statement is involved

Tags: php, sql, pdo

My select statement does not work when I add the WHERE statement.

The following code returns something:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM statement";
$stmt = $dbconn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':words'=>$words));
```

But this does not:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM statement WHERE words='(:words)'";
$stmt = $dbconn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':words'=>$words));
```

I am not sure why.  You may think it's because there is not statements object whose "words" element is equal to $words, but there is... I can run this loop with the first code:

```
foreach ($stmt as $s)
{
    var_dump($words, $s['words'], ($words==$s['words']));
    echo "<br>";
}
```

and here is my output:

```
string(4) "test" string(5) "test1" bool(false) 
string(4) "test" string(5) "test2" bool(false) 
string(4) "test" string(4) "test" bool(true)
```

So what's the deal?  I have no idea why this doesn't work.  Please let me know if I'm doing something extremely stupid.

Comment: what is that `'(:words)'`? Where  did you get it? Why don't you use the right syntax?

Comment: why wont directly put the variable on your sql query? Is that difficult?

Comment: @Kaii because it would spoil the whole idea of using PDO prepared statements and protection from SQL injection?

Comment: @YourCommonSense thumbs up .. didn`t see that.. your right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per PDO works you may not need extra apostrophe for your params. PDO automatically will work depend on type of variable. So this will work fine.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM statement WHERE words=:words";
$stmt = $dbconn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':words'=>$words));
```

Comment: Atleast gave reason for down vote, So person can understand what he suggest wrong. ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can try this below:

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM statement WHERE words in (':words')";`
`$statement->execute(array(':words' => $words));`

It will not give you result if you use () within single quote.

Thanks